# ml-py svm converges but classifying wrongly

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I am trying to do some classification task with python and SVM.

From collected data I extracted the feature vectors for each class and created a training set. The feature vectors have n-dimensions(39 or more). So, say for 2 classes I have a set of 39-d feature vectors and a single array of class labels corresponding to each entry in the feature vector.Currently, I am using mlpy and doing something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import mlpy 

svm=mlpy.Svm('gaussian') #tried a linear kernel too but not having the convergence
instance= np.vstack((featurevector1,featurevector1))
label=np.hstack((np.ones((1,len(featurevector1),dtype=int),-1*np.ones((1,len(featurevector2),dtype=int)))
```

#Assigning a label(+1/-1) for each entry in instance, (+1 for entries coming from 
  #featurevector 1 and -1 for featurevector2

```
svm.compute(instance,label) #it converges and outputs 1
svm.predict(testdata) #This one says all class label are 1 only whereas I ve testing data from both classes
```

Am I doing some mistake here? Or should I use some other library? Please help.

Comment: mlpy is great tool. if you have time, then watch SVM lectures on http://www.ml-class.org/ . First you can normalize your features, then you should find out precision&recall metrics to measure variance/bias, which helps to make next decisions like to change parameter C or sigma. Or gather more data, or clean exitisting data.

Comment: Thanks @timgluz I have been following ml-class.org For this particular problem I want to use a classifier something that can work like a black box and predict the class label of test data after I train it on training data. My input data set is a set of music signals converted to 39-d features, no scope for gathering more of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use mlpy, but `np.ones((1,len(featurevector1))` should perhaps be just `np.ones(len(featurevector1))` --
print `.shape` of each to see the difference.
(If you have a link to public data anything like yours, could you post it please ?)

Comment: got it, a row vector is all that I needed. I modified the same and tried but it didn't work. Tried libsvm on python and surprisingly it worked on the above problem and gave me correct results.